# How can I analyse all the tracks contained in a folder with Traktor 2?

Tags: software, dj, mixing, traktor

I want to analyse all the tracks contained in a folder with Traktor 2. Using right click on folder (in Traktor's browsing window) + "Analyze (Async)" only analyses tracks located at the root of the folder, and ignore the tracks located in the subfolders. How can I analyse all the tracks contained in a folder?

[image]

Comment: Looks like someone else had a similar problem on [this thread](http://www.native-instruments.com/forum/showthread.php?170575-T-Pro-2-Track-Analysis-%28Folders%29). Maybe the suggested solution will help you. I can't really say since I don't use Traktor.

Comment: @Dom Thanks, indeed it seems to be the only solution (I would have preferred not to have to import the tracks). I summarized the thread as an answer and added some screenshots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tested with Traktor 2.6.5 on Windows 7 x64 Ultimate:

Go to Traktor's preferences and check "Analyze news imported tracks".

[image]

Then in Traktor's browsing window, go the folder you want to analyze and right-click "Import to Collection". It will analyze all tracks contained in this folder including its subfolders (and recursively):

[image]

If anyone knows how to analyse all the tracks contained in a folder without having to import into the collection, please add it as an answer.